# Background Queries in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query in background using nohup command

```
[mysql@VM ~] nohup mysql -u <user> -h <host> -p<password> db_name -e "Select * from table_name;" &
```

how can I store the result of this query?
It does not show the result on the console after the job is done

Answer (score 0):

this is not a sql question , but you can redirect the output result of nohup to a file for example :

```
nohup {you command comes here} > result.txt
```